# How to close Outlook using VBA from MS Access

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to close Outlook before creating an appointment. My appointment will only get created when Outlook is closed. So I want to close/quit Outlook so the user will not have to.  How do I close Outlook using VBA from MS Access?

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim olApt As AppointmentItem

  Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With olApt
    End With
   End If

  Set olApt = Nothing
  Set olApp = Nothing
ExitProc:
Exit Sub
```

Comment: *My appointment will only get created when outlook is closed.* ... Unless this is your personal or business logic this is not true of the Outlook object model.

Comment: an error occurs if an instance of outlook is running , If I have outlook closed before running the command then the appointment will be added .

Answer (score 0):

Call `olApt.Quit` method.

You might want to check that `Application.Explorers.Count = 0` and `Application.Inspectors.Count = 0` to make sure you don't kill the instance the user is working in.