# Closing an email opened with OpenSharedItem?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have the below code which works up until I try to move the file once I have extracted the attachment.

The error says the file is still open. I confirmed that when I try to move it manually.

```vb
Filename = Dir(RFQFolder)
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
'Open .msg file in Outlook 2007+
Set outEmail = outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(RFQFolder & Filename)
        
For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
    If outAttachment.Filename Like "*.xls*" Then
        ROUploadFile1 = RFQFolder & outAttachment.Filename
        outAttachment.SaveAsFile RFQFolder & outAttachment.Filename
    End If
Next
outEmail.Close olDiscard
Set outEmail = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing
Set outAttachment = Nothing
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
oFS.moveFile Source:=RFQFolder & "\" & Filename, Destination:=Newpath & "\" & Filename
Set oFS = Nothing
```

Comment: Appears outEmail is closed but RFQFolder & "\" & Filename is not.

Comment: but outEmail = RFQFolder & Filename. So when I close outEmail isnt that closing the open file?

Comment: There are many questions about apparently closed items, applications, ... remaining in memory. You could try setting outAttachment to Nothing in the loop if more than one attachment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465055/administrator-limited-number-of-outlook-items/64487314#64487314 . You could try `outApp.Quit`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958874/how-to-close-outlook-using-vba-from-ms-access

Comment: The idea from icebird76 is feasible but move the Outlook item then process the attachments.

Comment: You may have to declare each dot notation object (outEmail.Attachments for example) as a variable and make sure to close them when finished. Take a look at the 1st answer on this link (marked best answer). https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c9ebdbd-7317-432d-b4e9-918cbf9f5728/openshareditem-it-is-being-used-by-another-process

Comment: @icebird76 i don't understand the syntax here. can you please help with the actual code. I know what you are trying to say just don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

If moving the file is the problem, why not save it directly where you need it?

```
Filename = Dir(RFQFolder)
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    'Open .msg file in Outlook 2007+
    Set outEmail = outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(RFQFolder & Filename)
    
    For Each outAttachment In outEmail.Attachments
        If outAttachment.Filename Like "*.xls*" Then
        ROUploadFile1 = RFQFolder & outAttachment.Filename
        outAttachment.SaveAsFile Newpath & "\" & Filename 'Changed the save path
        End If
        Set outAttachment = Nothing
    Next
outEmail.Close olDiscard
Set outEmail = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing
```

Comment: even if I save a copy to the new folder i still have to close the open instance of the file in the background

Comment: @DavidR I updated my code. Try moving the Set outAttachment = Nothing inside the loop right before Next. This should close out the file before moving on to the next one.

Comment: @iceberg the code is confusing but the item to be moved is outEmail "RFQFolder & "\" & Filename", not the attachment "RFQFolder & outAttachment.Filename". Still releasing the attachment memory may allow outEmail  to be moved.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood then. I thought it was to move the attachments out.

Comment: @icebird76 this did not work. I am still getting the Runtime Error 70 Permission Denied. When I try to move the file manually it tells me the file is open.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `Attachments` collection (`outEmail.Attachments`) - you need to either

1. Store the reference in a dedicated variable and release it by setting to `Nothing`
2. Avoid using "for each" loops - they keep reference to *all* colleciton items.
3. The easiest - move all that code into a separate sub: this way all internal (to that sub) variables will be released by VBA when the sub exits. You can call `MoveFile` outside of that sub.